# #import directive imports wrong file

Tags: ios, preprocessor, objective-c-category

Searched it already on the site but couldn't find an answer.
I have often files in my projects which are imported by reference. Mostly they are part of a whole project where I can run test cases etc.

So here is my Problem.
I import (by reference) a category, e.g. AppDelegate+Category.h/.m in my newly created project.
AppDelegate+Category.h imports the AppDelegate.h. But in my new project the category imports the AppDelegate from my testing project.

How can I overcome that problem so that the AppDelegate.h from my new project imported?

Comment: Why have you got a Category on your AppDelegate?, this smells to me. What is in this category? Sounds like you're giving too much responsibility to your Application Delegate.

Comment: I found this quite useful as you often have objects you have to place in a central place but want to keep the AppDelegate.m file clear of methods which deal with those objects.

Comment: Yeah, I often have these too. Usually they are re-usable, so I package them into a Controller class that I can re-use between projects. Sometimes this is a singleton, sometimes not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I know to this is to make folders for your categories, and put the category .h and .m in that folder. You can add the whole folder to other projects, and the non-category import will use the local one, not the one that is a folder above where the categories are.

Comment: I tested that solution before posting it :)

Comment: Hah - Ich war dort vor 30 Jahren. In diesen Zeit habe ich in Wien gewohnt. Jetzt arbeite ich im New York Stadt - in meine Firma findet man eine Osterreicherin, und eine halb-Deutsch Fräulein. Ich hoffe im Zukunft Berlin zu besuchen. In 1970s war ich manchmal in beide Ost und West Deutschland.